# how to create order programmatically without applying price rules

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, price-rules

How to skip applying price rules while creating an order programmatically?

Code looks like this (shortened)

```
/** @var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote */
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
         ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(['qty' => 1]));
$quote->getBillingAddress()->addData([..]);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->addData([..]);
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('my_own_shipping_module')
            ->setPaymentMethod('payment_method');

$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'payment_method'));

$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Skipping collectTotals() didn't help.

Comment: Try to set shipping methods as flatrate_flatrate

Answer (score 1):

@method Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Item setNoDiscount(int $value)

```
foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $item->setNoDiscount(1);
}
```

Place this before

```
$quote->collectTotals();
```